# par_unseq and "vectorization-unsafe" functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, lock-free, stdatomic

I'm confused about the restrictions imposed by the `par_unseq` execution policy and the idea of "*vectorization-unsafe*" functions.

I get the general idea: The `par_unseq` execution policy allows the compiler to perform vectorization, and so a single thread can interleave instructions between different function instances.  Because of this, using something like a mutex can cause deadlock because of instruction reordering.

But what about lock-free atomic algorithms, such as a compare_exchange loop?  Or wait-free atomic algorithms, such as an atomic reference counting mechanism?

I initially assumed these would be okay.  However, the [explanation at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) says:

> Unsequenced execution policies are the only case where function calls
>   are unsequenced with respect to each other, meaning they can be
>   interleaved. In all other situations in C++, they are
>   indeterminately-sequenced (cannot interleave). Because of that, users
>   are not allowed to allocate or deallocate memory, acquire mutexes, use
>   non-lockfree std::atomic specializations, or, in general, perform any
>   vectorization-unsafe operations when using these policies
>   (vectorization-unsafe functions are the ones that ***synchronize-with***
>   another function, e.g. `std::mutex::unlock` synchronizes-with the next
>   `std::mutex::lock`)

This is confusing because on the one hand it says that lock-free `std::atomic` operations are okay, but on the other hand it says that a *vectorization-unsafe* function is any function that **synchronizes with** another function.  The term "synchronizes with" in the C++ standard doesn't mean only mutexes - it means any atomic operation that synchronizes with another, such as an atomic load using `std::memory_order_acquire` that synchronizes with an atomic store using `std::memory_order_release`.  Such operations can be lock-free or wait-free, but still synchronize with each other in order to guarantee an ordering between threads.

So is it okay to use for example acquire/release operations with lock-free `std::atomic` variables (as long as the algorithm used is actually lock-free, i.e. forward progress is guaranteed by at least one thread)?  Or does `par_unseq` forbid ANY synchronization whatsoever (i.e. only relaxed atomic operations can be used safely)?

Comment: Note that atomics still could used, with any memory order, as long as it's thread private hence useless and doesn't synchronize. So it's clear the spec is utter BS.

Answer (score 2):

cppreference.com is not authoritative. The actual C++  standard says [nothing](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#algorithms.parallel) about using atomics inside an unsequenced algorithm and simply excludes all *vectorization-unsafe* operations. The goal is to eliminate any dependency between iterations.

An unsequenced execution policy is allowed to execute multiple iterations at the same time *in the same thread*. That breaks the usual happens-before semantics and forward-progress guarantees and can lead to a deadlock. For example a CAS loop waiting for an outcome of a previous iteration might never finish because the program is reordered to execute 8 such loops, followed by a vector operation.

```
int a[100]{};
std::atomic<int> busy = 0;
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int& x) {
    int expected;
    while (!busy.compare_exchange_strong(expected = 0, 1)) {} // might deadlock
    x++;
    busy = 0;
});
```

In practice you wouldn't want to mix vectorized code with atomic access, as the former is used in performance-critical code, and the latter is very slow. A vectorizing compiler will probably also be unable to vectorize such code.

Comment: So would you say then that the only safe use of atomics inside a `par_unseq` function would be relaxed atomics that don't synchronize with anything?  I'm not sure I understand how a lock-free CAS loop could ever deadlock..., even if the program is reordered.

Comment: If you don't synchronize with anything then it should be okay technically but will probably not vectorize well, if at all; x86 has no atomic vector instructions, for example. If you have a concrete use-case in mind, please share so we can evaluate/comment on it.

Comment: Technically, a `movq xmm0, qword [mem]` load and the corresponding store is guaranteed atomic if `mem` is 8-byte aligned.  I think you meant no atomic RMW vector instructions, which is true.  (Fun fact: in practice 16 and 32-byte aligned SIMD loads / stores are atomic in many CPUs, but frustratingly there's no CPUID feature bit for it so software can't safely take advantage.  Fun fact 2: AMD K10 has atomic 16-byte XMM load/store within a package, but tearing on 8-byte boundaries between different cores over hypertransport, so we really need vendor guarantees to safely take advantage.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, no vendor guarantee of no tearing, let alone RMW.

Answer (score 0):

It says you cannot use non-lock free `std::atomic` operations.  It does *not* say that you *can* use lock free `std::atomic` operations, nor does it say that you *cannot* use lock free `std::atomic` operations.

So the possibility of using lock free `std::atomic` operations is there, but you still need to ensure that they meet the other criteria (like not synchronizing with another function).

Comment: "It does not say that you can use lock free" - I believe you mean "It does not say that you cannot use lock free"

Comment: @JesperJuhl I guess that depends on how you want to look at it, since it doesn't actually say either way.  I've added a bit in an attempt to clarify my point.

Comment: The way I interpret your answer is that you are basically saying that you can only use relaxed atomic operations safely